# Using Excel to run a statement many times

Tags: excel, oracle, dbeaver

I am trying to use excel to update a list of part numbers in my database:

```
UPDATE 
  stock s 
SET 
  s.STC_AUTO_KEY = 2 
WHERE s.WHS_AUTO_KEY = 2 AND 
EXISTS(
  SELECT 
    p.PNM_AUTO_KEY 
  FROM 
    PARTS_MASTER p 
  WHERE 
    s.PNM_AUTO_KEY=p.PNM_AUTO_KEY AND p.PN='102550');
UPDATE 
  stock s 
SET 
  s.STC_AUTO_KEY = 2 
WHERE s.WHS_AUTO_KEY = 2 AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 
    p.PNM_AUTO_KEY 
  FROM 
    PARTS_MASTER p 
  WHERE 
    s.PNM_AUTO_KEY=p.PNM_AUTO_KEY AND p.PN='204-060-444-003');
```

The statements run without semicolons, but when I try to run more then one at once and use semicolons I get the error:

> SQL Error [911] [22019]: ORA-00911: invalid character
>
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

so... it looks like I don't know how run run more then one basic statement at once.

I am using DBeaver to interact with a Oracle database.

Thanks guys, sorry if this a no-brainer.

Comment: I added the DBeaver tag as this is very likely a front-end application question, rather than either Excel or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a blank line between each update statement if possible. You can do this easily with a text editor that supports regular expressions, just replace ';\n' with ';\n\n'

Comment: There may be some special characters being copied out of Excel.  Try typing one of the queries out by hand in your editor and see if it runs.